# Black screen with sound when starting Counter Strike Source

Tags: graphics, steam

I've recently installed Steam on 12.04. Whenever I try and run Counter Strike Source, it starts, makes the sounds, but the screen is black. I think it has something to do with my drivers not supporting Open Gl 3.0 or something. Counter Strike 1.6 works perfectly, as you would expect, but Source plays the sound over a black screen. I'm using open source Gallium drivers; I don't want to use fglrx as I've had issues with it in the past. Here's my system information from Steam:

```
SSSE3: Supported 
SSE4a: Supported 
SSE41: Unsupported 
SSE42: Unsupported 

Network Information: 
Network Speed: 

Operating System Version: 
Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS (64 bit) 
Kernel Name: Linux 
Kernel Version: 3.5.0-23-generic 
X Server Vendor: The X.Org Foundation 
X Server Release: 11103000 
X Window Manager: Compiz 
Steam Runtime Version: <Runtime enabled> 

Video Card: 
Driver: X.Org Gallium 0.4 on AMD RS880 

Driver Version: 2.1 Mesa 8.0.4 
Desktop Color Depth: 24 bits per pixel 
Monitor Refresh Rate: 59 Hz 
VendorID: 0x1002 
DeviceID: 0x9715 
Number of Monitors: 1 
Number of Logical Video Cards: 1 
Primary Display Resolution: 1366 x 768 
Desktop Resolution: 1366 x 768 
Primary Display Size: 16.14" x 9.06" (18.50" diag) 
41.0cm x 23.0cm (47.0cm diag) 
Primary VRAM Not Detected 

Sound card: 
Audio device: Realtek ALC662 rev1 

Memory: 
RAM: 2742 Mb 

Miscellaneous: 
UI Language: English 
LANG: en_GB.UTF-8 
Microphone: Not set 
Total Hard Disk Space Available: 20158 Mb 
Largest Free Hard Disk Block: 6586 Mb 

Installed software: 

Recent Failure Reports:
```

From what I've read, it seems like my graphics card should be compatible with open gl 3.0 (though I may be wrong) It seems that what I would need to do is find out how to get that support without wrecking my system. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. Any help would be very much appreciated, as I'm very new to Linux in general.

Answer (score 0):

Please ask in the Steam for Linux community group or on https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues
It is advisable that you use the latest proprietary drivers for Steam for Linux.

Comment: Thanks, I'll post this there. My PC won't get past GRUB on proprietary drivers...

Answer (score 0):

You know, you need to install fglrx...
First you need to upgrage/downgrade your x-server version to 1.12. You could use this PPA:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:makson96/fglrx`

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Install fglrx:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-legacy
```

Reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```